# Why Drupal 8 page messed up when I migrate from Bluehost to a local server?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I have a Bluehost server account and I have some Drupal 8 sites on it. The problem that I face is that when I try to migrate from Bluehost to a local server, the page works but is all messed, incluiding styles, images, menu items, etc. Also the back-end admin menu is messed.

It's weird, because if I do the reverse process, that is, from a local server to Bluehost, the site does work perfectly.

Does anybody have a hint of what's going on?

Thanks!

Comment: Difficult to answer from here. As we don't know how your servers are configured. My first guess would be `.htaccess` config. Possibly `RewriteBase`.

Comment: Yep, It was that. Thanks!

Comment: did you cleared all the site caches on your local.

Comment: Check from browser debugger, network tab what files are not loaded well. Maybe web server don't have access right to serve them, maybe files are missing...

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to answer from here. As we don't know how your servers are configured. My first guess would be `.htaccess` config. Possibly `RewriteBase`.

Change

```
# If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,
# uncomment the following line:
# RewriteBase /
```

to

```
# If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,
# uncomment the following line:
RewriteBase /
```

or vice versa.